# does not work recurring paypal sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

my php code generates html form which is submitting automatically with redirection of customers:

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="vm_paypal_form" id="vmPaymentForm" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="bolpav@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="otmjboutim6sl98u6olis61nm7" /
><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/devportal/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=vmplg&amp;task=pluginresponsereceived&amp;on=3L99030&amp;pm=1&amp;Itemid=166&amp;lang=" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/devportal/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=vmplg&amp;task=notify&amp;tmpl=component&amp;lang=" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/devportal/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=vmplg&amp;task=pluginUserPaymentCancel&amp;on=3L99030&amp;pm=1&amp;Itemid=166&amp;lang=" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="VirtueMart_Cart_PPA" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://example.com/devportal/images/virtuemart/vendor/" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order Number: 3L99030" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="105" />
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="52" />
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />
<input type="submit"  value="Please wait while redirecting to PayPal" />
</form>
```

After this form is submited i see page with order number, price and  message : ". To complete your checkout using PayPal, please log in." After i click Login button then it redirects me to login page . But after i login then it open dasboard and forgets about payment . So payment procedure gets broken.  I am using Sanbox business account for seller and sandbox personal account for customer. Can anybody help?

Comment: This is an old post, but without any answers. I am experiencing the same thing. On my webshop, everything seem to work properly, but every time the "return to merchant site" button in PayPal is pressed, I get back to the "Please log in" page on the Webshop. When logging in, the return URL is provided, but I dont get the POST variables needed to set the order as Completed. 

Does anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue at PayPal's end. The engineering team is working on this for a fix. Will update here once it gets fixed.